# Why does visual studio crash when opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio

I've been having some issues using visual studio 2017. Whenever I try to open a solution, it immediately crashes. I've tried reinstalling and repairing it. I tried installing the 2013 version, but I still get the same behavior. I tried resetting settings, starting in safe mode, and deleting the .suo file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it happen when you open any solution, or just one particular solution?

Comment: It happens with any solution.